# C++ make type of variable depend on context?

Tags: c++, c++14, variable-templates

I have the following code:

```
// Case #1
float f = 1.0f;
float f2 = sqrt(f * pi);

// Case #2
double d = 1.0;
double d2 = sqrt(d * pi);
```

Is there any way to define the variable `pi` so that `operator*` and `sqrt` will operate on `float`s in Case #1, but will operate on `double`s in Case #2?

Perhaps it might be possible with C++14 variable templates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sort of. You can certainly define such a `pi`:

```
template <class T> constexpr double pi = 3.14159...;
template <> constexpr long double pi<long double> = 3.14159...L;
template <> constexpr float pi<float> = 3.14159...F;
```

But you have to specify which `pi` you want:

```
float f2 = sqrt(f * pi<float>);
double d2 = sqrt(d * pi<double>);
```

---

More directly, you could define some `pi` object that just has overloaded `operator*` depending on the type:

```
struct Pi {
    template <class T> 
    decltype(pi<T>) operator*(T val) { return val * pi<T>; }

    template <class T> 
    friend decltype(pi<T>) operator*(T val, Pi) { return pi<T> * val; }
};
```

That lets you get the syntax you want, but that's weird, don't do it.

Comment: @T.C. Something like that?

Comment: You may make it simplier - default implementation should define `double` value instead of `int`. `template <class T> constexpr double pi = 3.0;`

Comment: @Orient Great idea.